# Hpricot empty link element from RSS

Tags: ruby, rss, hpricot

I'm currently parsing an RSS feed using Hpricot in Ruby.

All the elements are retrievable, except the  element.

This is what I'm doing:

The guid works, whereas the link fails, when I do ("/link").inspect it says it's an empty element. Although if you look at the feed, all the items have link elements with values.

```
doc = Hpricot.parse(open("http://www.highways.gov.uk/rssfeed/rss.xml"))   
(doc/:item).each do |xml_product|
  puts xml_product.search("/guid").first.children.first.raw_string
  puts xml_product.search("/link").first.children.first.raw_string
end
```

Any thoughts on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is malformed xml that you try to retrieve:

```
<link />http://www.trafficengland.co.uk/map.aspx?isTrafficAlert=true&amp;lat=53.4363602900352&amp;lon=-2.31328109635184
```

Hence when you prepare `/link` query you get `NoMethod` error because `link` elements are empty.

**UPDATE**

It seems to be problem of `hpricot`. Try `nokogiri` instead:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.highways.gov.uk/rssfeed/rss.xml"))   
doc.xpath("//item").each_with_index do |xml_product|
  puts xml_product.xpath('guid').text
  puts xml_product.xpath('link').text
end
# =>
     391532
     http://www.trafficengland.co.uk/map.aspx?....
     ....
```

Comment: I can't seem to see this malformed xml in the source?